# How to grep a value in a file and print it in another file based on FILENAME

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have several file like `A_bla.csv`(i.e `B_bla.csv` `C_bla.csv` etc ...) (It's a subsampling of the real file in term of lign but the number of column is the real one) :

```
1,test,test2,55.2,test3
1,test,test2,96.3,test3
1,test,test2,64.2,test3
1,test,test2,97.2,test3
```

And a main file `main.tsv` (field separator = `\t`):

```
id  coverage    clade
A   wrongdata   20
B   wrongdata   19
C   wrongdata   19
```

And I want to print the field of the 89th line of the 4th column from each `*_bla.csv` file into the `coverage` column of `main.tsv` file. In order to do that, I need to use the FILENAME of the `*_bla.csv`file and use it as pattern with the `id` column of `main.tsv` file.

So far I tried :

```
for file in *_bla.csv ; do
r="$(basename -s "_bla.csv" $file)"
awk ... ; 
done
```

But I'm near to a start of answer. Do you have an idea how to do that using only tool that are by default in a Linux machine (awk,grep,sed,python,perl ...) ? Thanks

Comment: In your example, you want to replace `wrongdata` of line 2 with – let's say – `42A`, if this is the 4th field of line 89 in `A_bla.csv`?

Comment: Yes per example!  I don't know if it's helpful but the value is only numeric (i.e float)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us files that we can use to test our answers. Show us a minimal example and the output you would expect from that minimal example.  You mention "89th line". Why only that line? Will it always be the 89th line for all `*bla.csv` files?

Comment: @terdon The problem is that if I give several file with each time at least 89 line it would be indigest for the Helpers. That's why I subsample my question to be more digest

Comment: @nstatam then tell us to use line 3 instead of line 89, the principle is the same. But if you don't show us your expected output, how can we know we are giving you what you need?

Answer (score 1):

The unavoidable GNU `sed` one-liner:

```
sed '1n;h;s/\([[:alnum:]]\).*/sed -E "89!d;s_([^,]*,){3}__;s_,.*__" \1_bla.csv/e;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)wrongdata/\2\1/' main.tsv
```

What's the magic? We use the `e`xecute option to the `s`ubstitute command to extract the 4th field of the 89th line with another `sed` command. In detail:

- `1n` to leave the first line unchanged
- `h` to store the line in hold space before we mess it up
- `\([[:alnum:]]\).*` matches the whole line and captures the first alphanumeric field in `\(\)` so we can refer to it as `\1` in the replacement
- `sed -E "89!d;s_([^,]*,){3}__;s_,.*__" \1_bla.csv` is this replacement: All lines except for 89 will be `d`eleted, then the first three fields get deleted and finally everything after the new first field. So actually only the fourth field of line 89 survives, so this will be returned by the `e`xecution of the buffer
- Now we only need to append the save line from the hold space with `G` and use `s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)wrongdata/\2\1/` to replace `wrongdata` with the extracted field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using the awk utility. Must run from the directory where the csv files are.

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
  FS=="," && FNR==89 {
    split(FILENAME, a, "_")
    h[substr(a[1],3)] = $4
  }
  f=FS=="\t" {
    $2 = FNR>1&&($1 in h) ? h[$1] : $2
  };f
' FS=, ./*_bla.csv FS="\t" ./main.tsv

id  coverage  clade
A   35.8      20
B   65.7      19
C   35.8      19
```

---

```
perl -F, -lane '
  if (@ARGV) {
    89..89 && do{
      $h{($ARGV=~/^..(\w+)_/)[0]} = $F[3];
      close ARGV;
    };
  } else { #last file here
    @F = split "(\t)";
    $F[2] = $h{$F[0]} // $F[2];
    print($.>1?@F:$_)
  }
' ./*_bla.csv ./main.tsv
```

---

GNU sed. But first we grep out the 89th line,4th field from each of the CSV files, escape the data coming out to make it safe for plugging in the RHS of a sed s/// statement.

```
hold=$(
  grep -Pzo '^(?:.*\n){88}(?:[^,]*,){3}\K[^,]*' -- *_bla.csv |
  tr '\0' '\n'|
  sed -Ee '
    s/_.*:/\t/
    s:[\&/]:\\&:g
    $!s:$:\\:
  ')

sed -En \
  -e "1{x;s/.*/$hold/;x;}" \
  -e '
    1!G
    s/^(\S+\t)wrongdata(\t.*)\n\1([^\n]*)/\1\3\2/
    P
  ' \
./main.tsv
```

---

```
python3 -c '
import sys, pathlib, itertools
mainf = sys.argv[1]
fs,rs = ofs,ors = "\t","\n"
d,dlm = {},","
for p in pathlib.Path(".").glob("*_bla.csv"):
  if p.is_file():
    id = p.name[:p.name.find("_")]
    with open(p.name) as f:
      d[id] = [l.rstrip(rs).split(dlm)[3] for l in itertools.islice(f,88,89)][0]
with open(mainf) as f:
  for l in f:
    L = l.rstrip(rs).split(fs)
    print(L[0], d.get(L[0],L[1]), *L[2:], sep=ofs)
' ./main.tsv
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a problem when running your script, the output is a simily of the structure of the *bla.csv file; is like the FNR and NR are not in the good order or something. Do you know why ?

Comment: Edited my answer plus added a few more solutions using different tools.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F',|\t' '
FILENAME != "main.tsv" && FNR == 89 {
                        sub(/_.*$/, "", FILENAME)
                        A[FILENAME]=$4
                        }
FILENAME != "main.tsv"  {next}
A[$1]                   {$2 = A[$1]}
                        {print}
' *bla.csv OFS='\t' main.tsv
```

I see that there is no tab delimiter in the `main.tsv` file. Then it will be necessary to correct the pattern like this: `-F',|[[:blank:]]+'`

Comment: Unfortunately, [the code rendering system here eats the tabs](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5797/22222) which is probably why you don't see them in the OP's example.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a problem when running your script, the output is a simily of the structure of the *bla.csv file; is like the FNR and NR are not in the good order or something. Do you know why ?

Comment: @nstatam, thank you. I fixed the code

Comment: You can also make the code more universal and use the following construction instead of `FILENAME != "main.tsv"` the name of the last file to - `FILENAME != AGRV[ARGC-1]`.

Comment: @EdMorton, there are many input files, but the last one is needed. I would have liked the `/,/` pattern or the `!/,/` antipattern better. And @gest_7 decision is more reasonable `split(FILENAME, a, "_")`

Comment: @nezabudka Ah, I missed the multiple files part, I'll delete that comment. I didn't say anything about `/,/` or `split()`.